# Start new powershell window with partially typed command

Tags: powershell

I want to automate running a deployment script with powershell. I'm using an additional script to add a time of day check since I cannot modify the deployment script. What I have so far:

```
//time of day check -- working great
$args = "cd C:\\; .\myscript.ps1 -Arguments someArguments <appName>"
Start-Process powershell -wait -Verb runAs $args
```

So in essence
1. Open a powershell window,
2. Navigate to a directory,
3. Start typing *.\myscript.ps1 -Arguments someArguments* **and wait**,
4. **I** type *<appName>* and press enter,
5. myscript.ps1 does it's thing,
6. I close the created powershell window (it must not close automatically)

Comment: You could write a function with a mandatory parameter `-AppName`. The function will call `cd ...` and so on with the provided app name. If you call that function without an app name, PS will ask you to provide it, what would fit to item 4 of your wishlist.

Comment: But will the windows stay open afterwards

Comment: If you don't provide the mandatory parameter, it will stay open until you provide it or cancel the execution.

Comment: But the after providing the parameter and executing myscript.ps1 will the newly created window stay open?

Comment: Only if you add `-NoExit` to your `$args`.

Comment: The problem is it's not waiting for me to press enter before executing myscript.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function with a mandatory parameter `-AppName` to wrap your script above:

```bsh
function Do-AmazinglyCoolStuff {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$AppName
    )
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit cd C:\; .\myscript.ps1 -Arguments someArguments `"$AppName`"" -Wait -Verb runAs
}

Do-AmazinglyCoolStuff
```

It requires you to type in your AppName if you do not provide it directly (`Do-AmazinglyCoolStuff -AppName MyApp`). It then opens a new PS window, sets the location, executes `myscript.ps1` with your desired arguments including the AppName and after `myscript.ps1` finished, the opened PS window remains open due to `-NoExit`.